# Computing the homology of a particular space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be the space obtained from an annulus by identifying each point $(x,y)$ on the inner circle with the point $(-2x,-2y)$ on the outer circle. Compute the homology groups $H_\bullet(X)$.

The question was taken from here: https://math.illinois.edu/system/files/inline-files/comp525_may19.pdf

Here is my attempt:
Consider the following CW complex $\emptyset = Y^{-1} \subset Y^0 \subset Y^1 \subset Y^2$:
[image: cell complex]

We obtain $X$ by identifying $\alpha \sim -\beta$ and naturally $x\sim y$. The chain complex is then:
$$
\begin{align*}
\dots \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0
\end{align*}
$$
Since $\partial_2 A = \beta -\gamma -\beta + \gamma = 0 $, $H_2(X) = \ker \partial_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Next, $\partial_1 \equiv 0$ and since $\text{im}\partial_2=0$, $H_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Finally $H_0(X) = \mathbb{Z}$ is trivial.

Is this computation right? I'm a bit confused because at first I didn't think we had $\alpha \sim -\beta$ and this gave me a different result.

Comment: The computation is incorrect, specifically the claim that $\partial_2A=0$.  Thinks precisely about how you have to attach the $2$-cell in order to obtain the space you want. The space $X$ is a rather famous space, by the way, maybe you can identify it.

Comment: My previous approach didn't identify $\alpha \sim -\beta$. This gave me $\partial A = \alpha +\beta$ and hence $H_2(X) = 0$. Then $\partial_1\alpha =\partial_1\beta = \partial_1\gamma=0$ together with the image of $\partial_2$ gave me $H_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: No, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are definitely inverse loops in $X$ due to the identification. The issue is that you're mixing up the orientations of the boundary of $A$.

Comment: hmm is the space simply a Klein bottle?

Comment: Yes. One way to see it is to note that the annulus is homeomorphic to a cylinder just by pulling up the center circle and straightening out the result, and then to form $X$ the boundary circles of the cylinder are being identified by an orientation-reversing map (the antipodal map). The result of this process is the Klein bottle.